# Py_initialize / Py_Finalize not working twice with numpy

Tags: python, c, numpy

On the second call of the following code, my app segfault, so I guess I am missing something :

```
Py_Initialize();
pName = PyString_FromString("comp_macbeth");
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
Py_DECREF(pName);

if(pModule == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    Py_Finalize();
    return;
}

pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "compute");
/* pFunc is a new reference */

if (!pFunc || !PyCallable_Check(pFunc) ) {
    PyErr_Print();
    Py_Finalize();
    return;
}

Py_Finalize();
```

The comp_macbeth.py is importing numpy. If I remove the numpy import, everything is fine. Is it a numpy bug, or am I missing something about imports ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [Py_Finalize docs](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#Py_Finalize):

> Some extensions may not work properly if their initialization routine is called more than once; this can happen if an application calls Py_Initialize() and Py_Finalize() more than once.

Apparently Numpy is one of those. See also [this message](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-March/040849.html) from Numpy-discussion.

Calling `Py_Initialize()` only once, and cleaning up [at exit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit), is the way to go. (And it's should be faster, too!)

Comment: I don't need to to the initialize / Finalize more than once, but I wanted to check if my understanding was correct

Comment: I have the same problem 11 years later. Should have been enough time to fix this bug...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74862962/exception-thrown-when-using-python-in-for-loop-in-c-script

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my module initialization part, but the URL does not exist anymore. In case it helps:

```
// http://numpy.scipy.org/numpydoc/numpy-13.html mentions this must be done in module init, otherwise we will crash
import_array();
```