# Embedded python - error while Numpy importing

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to embed python 2.7.3 in C++ and use Numpy library and I obtain runtime error while importing Numpy for the second time. Here is a simple code example (as smallest as possible) :

```
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
    for(int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++) {
        Py_Initialize() ;
        PyImport_ImportModule("numpy");
        Py_Finalize() ;
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

What's wrong with this ?

Answer (score 4):

From the `Py_Finalize` documentation docs you have:

> Some extensions may not work properly if their initialization routine is called more than
>   once; this can happen if an application calls Py_Initialize() and
>   Py_Finalize() **more than once**.

I wouldn't be surprised if Numpy is one of these extensions.

Update: looks like it is, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676314/py-initialize-py-finalize-not-working-twice-with-numpy).