# Unhandled exception at multiarray.pyd the 2nd time the program runs

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

I'm making a .dll plug-in in c++ and embedding python 2.7 in it.

Everything worked fine with simple .py programs until I imported a large program. The strangest thing is that the program runs with no problem the first time, but the second time an exception is raised:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x6731ADA1 (multiarray.pyd) in EuroScope.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000001.
```

(The Lib/Dll folders and modules are all copied to the .exe folder)

I've searched the web and there are a couple of persons with the same error but the solutions that worked for them don't for me. For example [here](https://code.google.com/p/ironclad/issues/detail?id=32)

I know this is a very specific error but I'm hoping that someone out there has already managed to work past it.
I won't post the code here because i think it's irrelevant for this bug and also because it's way too long

Edit: I managed to see the problem is specifically in `import numpy`

Comment: You need to run it in a debugger.  That exception looks like the program is attempting to write to address `1` (which is, of course, illegal).  The only way you can solve this is to see what piece of code is doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to work past this problem. It seems that some modules have problems when their initialization routines are called more than once, and `numpy`is one of those. The solution is to call `Py_Finalize()` only once at the very end of the program. `Py_Initialize()` can be called as many times as you want, as if Python is already initialized, `Py_Initialize()` is a non-op ...

And also, discovered that this solution turns the application faster since python doesn't need to restart every time there's a call to some of its function.

More information about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676314/py-initialize-py-finalize-not-working-twice-with-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem happens with `pyHook` and `pyxhook` library. Spent long time to figure out the reason of crash for those two modules but no clue available online. Now I am finding it is happening with `numpy` too. Hoping this one time `Py_Finalize()` will solve both of my problems.

The problem is solved after disabling python thread support in my embedded interpreter code by commenting the followings. By the way I am running the interpreter already in a POSIX thread created by my C code.

```
//PyEval_InitThreads();
//gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
//PyGILState_Release(gstate);
```

Now I can run my py.script with numpy and pyHook many times. However it will cause the following error message at the end of the C code if the module `thread` is imported in python script directly or by any other imported module.

```
Exception KeyError: KeyError(14288,) in <module 'threading' from 'C:\python27\Lib\threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Still I feel It needs a better solution.