# C DLL crack when called from Python

Tags: python, c, dll, interpreter

I've a DLL that embeds Python interpreter using the C/Python API. The DLL works fine if called one time, but if the DLL is called twice, the code cracks and my program catch memory error. 
The C code calling DLL is simple and the call to DLL function(Which calls Python interpreter) is done one time, if the second call(In the code) is not commented the code cracks and this happens only if "Numpy" is called in the Python code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <dll_simples.h>

int main() {
double in[] = { 4,2,5,4,2 };
double out[5] = {};
double a = 0;
double b = 0;


simuser(a,b,in,out);
//simuser(a, b, in, out); IF NOT COMMENTED -> ERROR

return 0;
 }
```

I've commented Py_Finalize() in the DLL as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134820/unhandled-exception-at-multiarray-pyd-the-2nd-time-the-program-runs) and this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676314/py-initialize-py-finalize-not-working-twice-with-numpy) affirms that from Py_Finalize() docs"Some extensions may not work properly if their initialization routine is called more than once; this can happen if an application calls Py_Initialize() and Py_Finalize() more than once." So i'd like to know why this happens and if any other thing could be done except calls "Py_Finalize()" only one time in the last call to DLL.

Comment: Why would you invoke `Py_` functions in that DLL? If it's supposed to be a Python module, write a proper Python module instead of using `ctypes` to access a C API.

Comment: I'm using a comercial software which simulates physical things, i can interact with the simulation to feedback information(Control theory), it can be done in this software with a DLL, that i'm using with python interpreter because my feedback function are in python. I'd like to have a code in order to debug my DLL with python functions, so i thought that call my DLL from a python script would allow me to test the DLL(with python interpreter and my python functions inside it).

Comment: Okay, makes sense. The problem is that the Python DLL is only loaded into the process once and your calls from the DLL mess with data structures that the interpreter (python.exe) sets up. Two hacks come to mind: One is to link the DLL statically. The other is to link the DLL to a renamed Python DLL, so that the OS loads them twice. Another option is to not talk to the DLL from within the same process, i.e. create a wrapper process that you communicate with via stdio streams or sockets (e.g. ZeroMQ for ease of use).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I've the same problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676314/py-initialize-py-finalize-not-working-twice-with-numpy), and i think that this problem is already in the knowledge of Python/C API developpers as commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676314/py-initialize-py-finalize-not-working-twice-with-numpy).

Comment: Ok, so you need *Py\_Initialize* when the *.dll* is called from a *C* *.exe*. How do you cope with *Python* code? *Py\_RunString*? You should add more info to the question. On the other hand *Py\_Initialize* checks if interpreter is already initialized, and if yes it does nothing. Also what is the *Python* version?

Comment: @CristiFati I've edited the question including more information and the point that i'm now.

Comment: I have a different understanding on the problem. In the question you mention, @Budelon, the sequence is init, finalize, init, finalize. The sequence here is init, init, finalize, finalize. The outer calls are made by `python.exe`, while the inner calls are hidden in the depths of a DLL. In short, two parts of the program both use Python independently from each other and they both call init and finalize, causing corruption of global (!) data structures.

Comment: You should have left the removed parts in the question. Also I was curious what was in the *C* *.dll* function between the initialize and finalize calls.

Answer (score 0):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

*dll00.h*:

```c
#pragma once

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if defined DLL0_EXPORTS
#    define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API int dll00Func00(double t, double delta, unsigned int size, const double *pIn, double *pOut);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

*dll00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Python.h"
#define DLL0_EXPORTS
#include "dll00.h"

#define C_TAG "From C .dll"


int dll00Func00(double t, double delta, unsigned int size, const double *pIn, double *pOut) {
    int res = 0;
    printf("%s: in function\n", C_TAG);
    const int isInit = Py_IsInitialized();
    // Modify array calling Python functions
    if (!isInit) {
        printf("%s: initializing Python interpreter\n", C_TAG);
        Py_Initialize();
    }
    res = PyRun_SimpleString("print(\"From Python (within C .dll): test\")");
    for (unsigned  int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        pOut[i] = pIn[i] * t + delta;
    }
    if (!isInit) {
        printf("%s: uninitializing Python interpreter\n", C_TAG);
        Py_Finalize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*main00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "dll00.h"
#define SIZE 4


int main() {
    int res = 0;
    double in[SIZE] = { 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0 };
    double out[SIZE] = { 0 };
    res = dll00Func00(2, 0.5, SIZE, in, out);
    printf("Output array:\n");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%.03f ", out[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

*code00.py*:

```c
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.dll"


def main(*argv):
    DblPtr = ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)
    size = 5
    DblArr = ct.c_double * size

    dll00 = ct.PyDLL(DLL_NAME)
    dll00Func00 = dll00.dll00Func00
    dll00Func00.argtypes = (ct.c_double, ct.c_double, ct.c_uint, DblPtr, DblPtr)
    dll00Func00.restype = ct.c_int

    in_arr = DblArr(*range(size))
    out_arr = DblArr()
    print("Output array:")
    for i in range(size):
        print("{:.3f}".format(out_arr[i]), end=" ")
    print("\n")
    res = dll00Func00(2, 2.5, size, in_arr, out_arr)
    print("Output array:")
    for i in range(size):
        print("{:.3f}".format(out_arr[i]), end=" ")
    print()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Notes**:

- In *Python*, use *ctypes.PyDLL* as you're (**indirectly**) calling *Python API* functions
- In the *.dll*, use [[Python 3.Docs]: Initialization, Finalization, and Threads - *int* **Py_IsInitialized**()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_IsInitialized)

  - As a side note, the *if* test is not needed in *Py_Initialize*'s case as *Py_Initialize* simply returns if the interpreter is already initialized (so I left it there just for consistency), but it is needed for *Py_Finalize* as one wouldn't want to uninitialize the interpreter while still in *Python*. 
    So *Py_Initialize* / *Py_Finalize* pair doesn't work on "reference count" (every *Py_Initialize* call requires an *Py_Finalize* one)
- Calling *Py_Initialize* / *Py_Finalize* in the function, seems like an overkill (if the function is being called multiple times). I'd do 2 wrapper functions in the *.dll* and call:

  - one at the beginning
  - the other at the end

  of the (*C*) program

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059937552>sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
> **********************************************************************
> ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.19
> ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> **********************************************************************
> [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
> dll00.h
> main00.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\include" dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll /LIBPATH:"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\libs"
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /W0 main00.c  /link /NOLOGO /OUT:main00_064.exe dll00.lib
> main00.c
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.h
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
> main00.c
> main00.obj
> main00_064.exe
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Output array:
> 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
>
> From C .dll: in function
> From Python (within C .dll): test
> Output array:
> 2.500 4.500 6.500 8.500 10.500
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06
>
> [prompt]> main00_064.exe
> From C .dll: in function
> From C .dll: initializing Python interpreter
> From Python (within C .dll): test
> From C .dll: uninitializing Python interpreter
> Output array:
> 20.500 22.500 24.500 26.500
> ```