# python calling C/C++ calling python

Tags: python, pythoninterpreter

I have a python3 application calling C/C++ functions.
In one of the C++ functions, I'd like to run a python interpreter.
It doesn't have to deal with the first python environment, the are totaly dissociated.

I tied to use [embed a pybind interpreter](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html#embedding-the-interpreter) but I got the following error "The interpreter is already running"

Comment: This seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937552, does the answer there help?

Comment: I'm not saying that it's impossible, but I can't help but wonder if there might be a better approach to this. If you're going to end up calling python functions anyway, why not just leave that part as pure python?

Answer (score 0):

I used this to call python function from C

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/calling-python-from-c-set-1/

and

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/calling-python-from-c-set-2/