# Memory leak when embedding python into my application

Tags: python, c++, memory-leaks, python-c-api, cpython

The following program, when linked against python 2.7.13 and run on Windows 10 slowly but steadily leaks memory.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Python version: " << PY_VERSION << std::endl;

    while (true)
    {
        Py_Initialize();
        //PyGC_Collect();
        Py_Finalize();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The interesting fact is that it seems not every iteration leaks memory. What I see, though, is that the reference count that python prints slowly increases by a (non-constant) count of approximately 90 per iteration regardless of the leak. Using the Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools I figured out that the leak is coming from a call to `PyImport_ImportModule()` when it reads a compiled module from disk (the actual call stack is several levels deep).

Are any additional cleanup steps necessary that I am not aware of? Or is there something about the Python garbage collector that might cause this and it is not a "real" memory leak?

Comment: I think generally you `initialize` once, and `finalize` once, so the leak is a constant, which makes it not a memory leak at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Py\_initialize / Py\_Finalize not working twice with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676314/py-initialize-py-finalize-not-working-twice-with-numpy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Py_Finalize` — Python/C API Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Finalize) (emphasis mine):

> <...>
>   **Bugs and caveats:** The destruction of modules and objects in modules is
>   done in random order; this may cause destructors (__del__() methods)
>   to fail when they depend on other objects (even functions) or modules.
>   **Dynamically loaded extension modules loaded by Python are not
>   unloaded.** Small amounts of memory allocated by the Python interpreter
>   may not be freed (if you find a leak, please report it). Memory tied
>   up in circular references between objects is not freed. Some memory
>   allocated by extension modules may not be freed. Some extensions may
>   not work properly if their initialization routine is called more than
>   once; this can happen if an application calls Py_Initialize() and
>   Py_Finalize() more than once.

Comment: @sigy http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8934/what-to-do-with-questions-when-the-answer-is-in-a-man-page

Answer (score 0):

Above answer puts it all together

```
#include <Python.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    wchar_t *name = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    Py_SetProgramName(name); 
    
    pythonlovesC();

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

void pythonlovesC()
{

    while (true)
    {
       // do your python stuff here  
       PyGC_Collect();
        
    }

}
```